# Sugarcrm dropdown value sorting

Tags: php, sugarcrm

This is my code :

In `custom/Extension/application/Ext/Utils/ or custom/include/custom_utils.php`

```
<?php

function getActiveReleases()
{
    $query = "SELECT id, name FROM releases where deleted=0 and status='Active' order by list_order asc";
    $result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($query, false);

    $list = array();
    $list['']='';
    while (($row = $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result)) != null) {
        $list[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
    }

    return $list;
}

unset($dictionary['MODULENAME']['fields']['FIELDNAME']['options']);
$dictionary['MODULENAME']['fields']['FIELDNAME']['function'] = 'getActiveReleases';
```

[Refrence From here](https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/08/24/howto-have-a-dropdown-field-that-gets-its-options-from-a-function/)

I did the same thing in my code and it is working fine except order by : **order by list_order asc** .
 Drop down should come in  order is like : **order by list_order asc** .
But sugar overriding it and sorting the drop down by key value of the drop down list by : **id**. 
I want key value as **ID** but sorting should be like : `order by list_order asc`

I search on Google but i did not found any way to do it so i am posting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this after your while statement?

```
asort($list);
return $list;
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php):

> This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their
>   correlation with the array elements they are associated with. This is
>   used mainly when sorting associative arrays where the actual element
>   order is significant.

Comment: Not working how? It's not sorting them, even after adding in the asort function before the return?

Answer (score 1):

replace this :

```
$list[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
```

by indexed array :

```
$arrayIndex = 0;
while (($row = $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result)) != null) {
    $list[$arrayIndex] = $row['name'];
    $arrayIndex++;
}
```

---

it isn't about `sugarcms` , it's about the php itself

while you are providing the `$row['id']` as an array key, which is sorted by nature ,

php will resort it by the order of this variable value

take this as a quick example : https://3v4l.org/8HjFB, i hope this make it more clear to you

Comment: But i need that key , i am using that key somewhere else also.

Comment: what about adding this as an individual element ? `$list[$arrayIndex] = $row` for example .

Comment: i did not understand

Comment: i mean adding the whole row [id, name] to the list array .

Comment: i am creating my array like this $list[$row['filed1']] = $row['filed2'].' - '.$row['filed3']; I am showing field2 and 3 and using field1 in back end.

Comment: set your array like following : `$list[$arrayIndex] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['name']);`